# C# WPF Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, window, storyboard

I am using WPF, On my main window whenever i try to do anything it gives me this error
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
These for example,

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
((Storyboard)this.FindResource("HideWindow")).Begin()
```

i seriously have no idea what is that and in massive need of help i cant execute the very first lines of my code.
More info:
I can't open another window, giving me thread is not STA error

```
LoginWindow objLoginWindow = new LoginWindow();
objLoginWindow.ShowDialog();
objLoginWindow = null;
```

this is the exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
Source=WindowsBase
StackTrace: at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value) 
at Menupedia.LoadingWindow.OpenNewWindow() in c:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\menupedia\Menupediaa\Menupedia\LoadingWindow.xaml.cs:line 51 
at Menupedia.LoadingWindow.TimeElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\menupedia\Menupediaa\Menupedia\LoadingWindow.xaml.cs:line 39 
at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
```

Comment: But you do not start a separate thread?

Comment: i tried using a different thread. okay it works and gets me to load the new window. but the other one is left back there i cant hide it in any way..

Comment: You mean the Storyboard is not executed? You might perhaps provide a bit more information of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The 2 lines of code doesn't execute at all and throws an exception
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your stack trace shows that you use a `System.Timers.Timer`. The `Elapsed` handler of Timer is called in a background thread, which does not allow direct access to UI elements. You have to call `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to access UI elements in the `Elapsed` handler.

It may however be easier to replace the Timer by a [`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a `Tick` event that is invoked in the UI thread, and hence allows safe access to UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that there is a separate thread trying to access an item which is owned by the UI thread, this creates a problem and to illustrate what that problem is I'm going to give you a simple example, if you have two steam trains running in parallel, what you're trying to do is get the 1st train to use the other trains coal, which obviously it can't, you would need to ask the train operator to stop so that he can let you access it.

Now the way to do that is this...

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
{
    //Access the UI thread and where the storyboard is located
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    ((Storyboard)this.FindResource("HideWindow")).Begin()
}));
```

Comment: okay i get what the problem means. but tbh it's not logical because i have only one thread which is the mainprogram that runs that window itself

Comment: As clemens stated, the System.Timers.Timer operates on a separate thread.